# BitmapImage ImageOpened Event Not fired

Tags: c#, events, windows-runtime, bitmapimage

Why is in this example the ImageOpened event not fired? I'm using it in a WinRT App for Win8.

```
BitmapImage myImage = new BitmapImage();        
myImage.ImageOpened += myImage_ImageOpened;
myImage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:/Assets/Image.png");


private void myImage_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int pixelHeight = (sender as BitmapImage).PixelHeight;
}
```

My problem is the ImageOpened event is not fired. I want to check the PixelHeight and PixelWidth of the Image but I can't if I don't get this event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WinRT has a lazy loading behavior. The Image won't be loaded unless you actually display it. If you really need to force loading in order to perform some layout adjustments you can use that kind of workaround to force loading :

```
 private async void Download()
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage image = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
        image.ImageFailed += image_ImageFailed;
        image.ImageOpened += image_ImageOpened;
        var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Logo.scale-100.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        var stream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
        await image.SetSourceAsync(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
    }

    void image_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog dg = new MessageDialog("Image Failed");
        dg.ShowAsync();
    }

    void image_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageDialog dg = new MessageDialog("Image Opened");
        dg.ShowAsync();
    }
```